# Vue is not detecting changes made with JQuery or JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js, vue-reactivity

I made a pen so you can see what I'm talking about: https://codepen.io/cristian-ayala/pen/rNOWwOO?editors=1111

Both, the input and the paragraph are binded to a value from Vue (anioPicker) but after 1 sec I change the value with jquery, but vue is not detecting the changes or maybe I do not register the event correctly. Paragraph still showing 2020 even when I already change it, but in vue instance still being 2020. Vue is only reflecting the changes if I type in or delete something. Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks for any help.

```js
var vm = new Vue({
    el: '#appRESBAR',
    data: {
        anioPicker: 2020,
    },
  methods:{
    
  },
  watch: {
        anioPicker: function(value) {
            console.log("watched property",value);
        }
    }
});


$(window).on("load", function(e) {
   setTimeout(function() {
        $("#anioDate").val(2012);
        console.log(document.querySelector('.yearpicker').value)
    }, 1000);
});
```

```css
.datePick {
    display: inline-block;
    background: #828282;
    transform: skew(-10deg);
    padding-left: 10px;
    font-weight: 500;
    padding-top: 0.5rem;
    padding-bottom: 0.5rem;
    padding-right: 10px;
    margin-top: 0.5rem;
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
    color: #ffffff;
}

.selectedDate {
    background-color: #224abed6;
}

.styleInput{
    margin: 0px;
    width: 38px;
    color: white;
    background: #4466c8;
    border: none;
    padding: 0;
    outline: none;
    border-radius: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="appRESBAR" style="text-align: center;">
  <div class="datePick selectedDate">
    <input type="text" id="anioDate" class="yearpicker styleInput" style="margin: 0;" v-model="anioPicker"></input>
  </div>
<p>La fecha es: {{ anioPicker }}</p>
</div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.16/dist/vue.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vue uses it's own VDom (Virtual DOM) to manage it's data and components. You're modifying the underlying DOM instance, which does not propagate those changes upwards to the VDom.

You must modify the value within the `vue` instance instead.

You can do this by directly mutating the value of the root `vm` instance in your case:

```js
vm.anioPicker = 2012
```